# Observing object properties with ReactiveCocoa 4 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

As a preface, this might be an incredibly simple and/or ignorant question.

In ReactiveCocoa 2.x, we were able to use RACObserve and RAC to observe properties of an object. From the documentation I can find in Reactive 3 and 4, we now use PropertyType to observe changes to an object property. I have so far been unsuccessful in being able to observe any property change when using MutableProperty or DynamicProperty.

```
class TempObject {
  var property: String
}

let tempObject = TempObject()
let propertyObserver: MutableProperty<String> = MutableProperty(tempObject.property)
```

From what I understand, I should be able to use propertyObserver to view changes to tempObject.property. I tried adding a map function to the signal producer from propertyObserver to see if it was firing, but don't see anything when updating tempObject.property. Again, could be a trivial thing that I am missing, thanks so much.

**Edit**

NachoSoto nailed it - I needed to make my property KVO compliant. I also ended doing this:

```
let tempObjectSignal: MutableProperty<TempObject> = MutableProperty(tempObject)
let propertyObserver: MutableProperty<String> <~ tempObjectSignal.producer.map({ $0.property })
```

And whenever tempObject.property is updated I make sure to call

```
tempObjectSignal.value = tempObject
```

This fires off all the necessary signals. I don't know if this breaks any best practices, though. Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MutableProperty(value)` creates a mutable property [**but only with `value` that as the initial value**](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/9eac35041b0fb5ac8b111416abf9a14c363544e4/ReactiveCocoa/Swift/Property.swift#L128).

What you want to use is [`DynamicProperty`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/9eac35041b0fb5ac8b111416abf9a14c363544e4/ReactiveCocoa/Swift/Property.swift#L180), which will use the Objective-C runtime and `KVO` to detect changes to an object's property:

```
let property = DynamicProperty(tempObject, "property")
```

For that reason, however, you need to make sure that the property you want to observe is part of the Objective-C runtime, by making the class a subclass of `NSObject`, and by either using the `dynamic` keyword:

```
class TempObject: NSObject {
    dynamic var property: String
}
```

Or using `@objc` to ensure that it gets exported to the runtime:

```
class TempObject: NSObject {
    @objc var property: String
}
```

Comment: Adding `dynamic` did the trick! Ends up being a bit less flexible than the way I added in the edit though. What do you think of having one parent tempObjectSignal, and then mapping all other signals from that?